# Can't redirect target of freeze operation via preventExtensions trap

Tags: javascript, javascript-proxy

Code:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var proxy;
    var realTarget;
    var target;

    realTarget = {};
    target = {};

    proxy = new Proxy(target, {
        isExtensible: function (target) {
            return Reflect.isExtensible(realTarget);
        },
        preventExtensions: function (target) {
            return Reflect.preventExtensions(realTarget);
        }
    });

    Object.freeze(proxy);
})();
```

Resulting error message:

```
[error] Line 20: Uncaught TypeError: 'preventExtensions' on proxy: trap returned truish but the proxy target is extensible
```

Why is this an error? What's the point of a proxy if I can't redirect this operation?

Answer (score 1):

Proxy traps have a set of so-called invariants they have to conform to.

One of these is that the `preventExtensions` trap may *only* return `true` if `[[IsExtensible]]` of the proxy's target returns `false` (i.e. if the target is really made inextensible).

You can work around this by returning `false` (signaling that making the object inextensible has failed):

```
preventExtensions: function (target) {
    Reflect.preventExtensions(realTarget);
    return false
}
```

Comment: Why is that restriction in place?

Comment: I *could* return `false` in the `preventExtensions` trap, but then the operation isn't completely forwarded to `realTarget`.